# Unity Text Component can't show all the text, how can this happened?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use Unity to create a game and use Text to show some message,but there was a bug not appear every time, that is,  the Text only show some of the context, and I set the horizontal overflow as wrap, the bellow picture is the bug:
[the good one, the text show "下注倒计时："](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvg0g.png)

[the bug one, the text show "下   ：","注倒计时" these three words just disapeared!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg100.png) 
 and the bug  only appeared on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is on the setting of the text... please see the image below. :)[image]

check this image some of the text is not visible. the image below show the text completely..

[image]

check the best fit so that. the text will fit the width and height... check the image below... hopefully this help. :D

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'v tried your solution and I didn't get the bug anymore, it's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This can be a font issue, Do you get this issue with the normal English font.
Are you using Unity UI or NGUI or any other plugin?

Comment: I didn't use other plugin, I just use  unity's UGUI to do my project, the font is offered by artiest in my team,  and I used this font at other Text components but they just worked fine.